# -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am working with UITableview i am displaying image, title,date and location name on tableview cell.When i click on tableview cell it will navigate to details view.in continuous process tableview to detail view and vice versa.After some navigations my application getting crash when i click on my UITableview cell.

Comment: Please post your code so we can offer some help.

Answer (score 27):

`NSArray` is designed to hold objects for every element -- `nil` is never a valid value at any `NSArray` index.

The error suggests your program is creating an array with a non-zero length, and that the first element is nil.

---

Hunch: You have declared a literal, something equivalent to:

```
NSNumber * n = nil;
NSArray * a = @[n]; // << runtime error creating this array
```

Of course, your program could instead be calling `-[NSArray initWithObjects:count:]` directly.

Answer (score 0):

1- Define a safe macro
`#define $safeArgs(...) [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:__VA_ARGS__, nil]`

2- Then use
`NSArray *array = [$safeArgs("objectsToSanitize") allObjects];`

This will use a set to cleanse your nil objects and then put them into an array